# Javascript - проблемы производительности

Tags: javascript, производительность

Одна из форм (которая сейчас в разработке) периодически буквально "убивает" ОС. Система, не только браузер, зависает напрочь. Причем воспроизвести не могу уже на многих системах, но у коллег вышло повторить на своих машинах. Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь с утечкой памяти, но насколько я понимаю, проблемы с ней возникают при длительной работе с формой. В моем же случае форму только открыли в браузере, выбрали значение в комбобоксе, и все - система мертва.

В чем может быть ошибка?

**Обновление**

Что еще примечательно, что все процессы ОС продолжают работать. Умирает УВВ. ничего не ввести, ни выбрать. Код показать не могу, да и продукт слишком большой. Мне бы понять хотя бы, какие ситуации могут к такому приводить.

Характеристики машин, на которых повторилась проблема: ОС Ubuntu 14.04 - Chromium 45 (ОЗУ 4, i5), ОС Ubuntu 10.04 - Firefox 41 (ОЗУ 16, i5). Делал виртуалку с такой же ОС, как первая машина и таким же браузером - повторить не смог. Форма обычная: при открытии дергает сервер на получение данных. На ней только инпуты для ввода или редактирования информации и комбобоксы + самописные директивы (timepicker) и ничего более (приложение на angular 1.3.7). На 1й машине воспроизводится всегда, на второй удалось повторить только 1 раз, потому мне сложно отследить проблему, тк появляется проблема не у меня. Нет даже замедлений работы интерфейса при работе формы. Сложно понять, в каком направлении хотя бы искать проблему.

Comment: Какая ОС, процессор, память? Какой браузер, плагины, версии? Может ли быть такое, что скрипт формы активирует какие-то плагины, напр. Java или играет видео?  Что происходит при выборе значения? ----- Найдите обработчик события выбора, и поставьте брейкпоинт или обрывайте исполнения сразу в его начале (`return;`) – это, наверное, избавит от зависания. Потом пошагово или по строке – пока не поймаете момент, вызывающий проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Без кода можно гадать очень долго, но так и не приблизиться к реальному ответу.
Первый кандидат на такое поведение - рекурсивные вызовы без остановки, либо итерации со слишком большим числом повторений.

Comment: Всю систему такое не должно же подвешивать – только процесс браузера?

Comment: не должно, но подвешивает)